# Remove text from meta tags from string file

Tags: php, regex

I would like to reset all of these metas so that they have empty content attribute. I have a regex that can do this if I know what the content is set to. Here is the example I have:

```
$string = preg_replace('/<meta content="website"[^>]+>/', '<meta content="website" property="og:type">',$stringFile);
```

Current metas:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="dynamic text here" property="og:title">
<meta content="lots of text ... lots of text ... lots of text " property="og:description">
<meta content="website" property="og:type">
<meta content="version" property="og:url">
<meta content="/folder/folder/folder/folder/logo.jpg" property="og:image">
```

Desired output (notice the text/html remains unchanged):

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="" property="og:title">
<meta content="" property="og:description">
<meta content="" property="og:type">
<meta content="" property="og:url">
<meta content="" property="og:image">
```

Comment: Something like this? https://regex101.com/r/9ptqiJ/1

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of...

```
<?php


$html = '<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="dynamic text here" property="og:title">...';

$domd = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$domd->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$domx = new DOMXPath($domd);
$items = $domx->query("//meta[@content]");

foreach($items as $item) {
  if (strpos($item->getAttribute('content'),'text/html') !== false) continue;
  $item->removeAttribute("content");
}

echo $domd->saveHTML();
```

...should do the trick. Avoid regex for manipulating html.

Alternatively, if condition using regex as suggested by Toto:

```
<?php


$html = '<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="dynamic text here" property="og:title">...';

$domd = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$domd->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$domx = new DOMXPath($domd);
$items = $domx->query("//meta[@content]");

foreach($items as $item) {
  if (preg_match('~\btext/html\b~',$item->getAttribute('content'))) continue;
  $item->removeAttribute("content");
}

echo $domd->saveHTML();
```

Comment: This is the way to go, but you must keep the ` text/html` as requested.

Comment: Oh yes. I missed that part.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the edit. I guess regex is in its element parsing the string inside the attribute value. However, I think it might be overkill in this case, I'd have probably used strpos myself. http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strpos.asp

Comment: Feel free to modify and change to strpos. It's your answer :)